# HTML Table validation error when combining rowspan and colspan on <th> element

Tags: html, html-table, w3c-validation

My code seams to work fine but trying to validate it at https://validator.w3.org/nu/#file

It gives me the error:

> Table column 2 established by element th has no cells beginning in it.

If I remove the rowspan attribute, I get no errors. How could this be?

```
<table>
    <caption>Average salary</caption>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2" rowspan="2">Occupation</th>
        <th colspan="2">Salary (kr)</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <th>Men</th>
        <th>Women</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Ambulance nurse</td>
        <td>37 400</td>
        <td>36 800</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Consultant system development</td>
        <td>43 000</td>
        <td>43 500</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">High school teacher</td>
        <td>35 000</td>
        <td>35 400</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Dentist</td>
        <td>44 400</td>
        <td>46 100</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Air lane leader</td>
        <td>65 700</td>
        <td>66 500</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Bar manager</td>
        <td>23 000</td>
        <td>23 000</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Home service assistant</td>
        <td>27 100</td>
        <td>27 400</td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

What I want to achieve is this structure

[image]

Comment: Remove `colspan` from first `<th>` .

Answer (score 0):

The solution was this code:

```
<table>
    <caption>Average salary</caption>
    <tr>

        <th rowspan="2">Occupation</th>
        <th colspan="2">Salary (kr)</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Men</th>
        <th>Women</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ambulance nurse</td>
        <td>37 400</td>
        <td>36 800</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Consultant system development</td>
        <td>43 000</td>
        <td>43 500</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>High school teacher</td>
        <td>35 000</td>
        <td>35 400</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Dentist</td>
        <td>44 400</td>
        <td>46 100</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Air lane leader</td>
        <td>65 700</td>
        <td>66 500</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Bar manager</td>
        <td>23 000</td>
        <td>23 000</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Home service assistant</td>
        <td>27 100</td>
        <td>27 400</td>

    </tr>
</table>
```